# Not able to focus on a pop up window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open an ftp page which pops up an authentication dialog. I am entering the authentication details using Robot class's Keypress events. But here if the focus is not on that pop up window then it types the authentication details in the other window which is in focus. As this pop up window is not a web element i cannot use driver.switchTo().window() as here i need to pass windowhandle which i am not getting. If somehow i can click on that driver window my focus will shift to user id textbox in authentication pop up. Please suggest a way to click on the driver window for which i dont know any element except title of the window. Or some other way to deal with window popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coordinates in Robot class:

```
robot.mouseMove(1005,10);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

and then use Keypress

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_2212401_2/Introduction-to-the-Java-Robot-Class-in-Java.htm

Of course you have to specify your coordinates for window. Notice, that this method may be unreliable - it depends on screen resolution, so if you test it on minimized browser and on full screen, it will fail.

As an alternative, you can use Sikuli bindings with java - http://www.sikuli.org/ - and use sikuli picture comparision to interact with popup. Unfortunatelly, it is also not as reliable as we would want.

You can also use other java library - https://github.com/twall/jna I don't know what your OS is, so you will probably have to change some lines.

```
public class selectHiddenWindow {
  public interface User32 extends W32APIOptions {   
     User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);  

     boolean ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int nCmdShow); 
     boolean SetForegroundWindow(HWND hWnd);  
     HWND FindWindow(String winClass, String title);  
     int SW_SHOW = 1;              
}  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
   User32 user32 = User32.instance;  
   HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow(null, "your title");  
   user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_SHOW);  
   user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);  
}
```

Source:   http://www.coderanch.com/t/562454/java/java/FindWindow-ShowWindow-SetForegroundWindow-effect-win

Comment: Coordinates of the window cannot be used as i am using two drivers and if the popup window is of the other driver then it will be behind the first driver so in this case if i click at the coordinates then too it would not work.

Comment: So if you know how to bring that window which i am using to the front please help

Comment: Added other option in edited post for your specified info. I didn't remove previos options as valid for some other situations

Comment: I may have to run these on different OS(32 or may be 64 bit) and also resolution may be different so i don't think i could use this.